# How can I make my custom "name@example.com" e-mail address if I'm the owner of "example.com"

Tags: email

I have a ".com" domain for 2 years. The only thing that I can modify is the nameservers, ns1, ns2, and ns3.

How can I make my own e-mail address for this domain? Do I really need to buy hosting?

I don't have a host right now, but I intend to make an application on a Django host, probably a Debian server, or maybe on Google app engine.

Answer (score 1):

No, you dont have to have a host. You can use Google apps: http://www.google.com/apps/
They have a free version if you don`t need more than 50 accounts.

Comment: @Elad Actually, Google is the host if you use Google Apps. Also by this time, it would be 10 free accounts only =(

Comment: @Jake - Dig up old posts and add pointless comments to them much?

Answer (score 0):

Find a web host to host your domain. The web hosting company usually uses branded control panel like plesk or cpanel. You can create your custom email name within that control panel under few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You do need DNS nameserver hosting. This is not the typical hosting plan. As Elad suggested for mail you can go for the free google apps.

If you had bought your domain from say GoDaddy, they provide a DNS Manager to edit your DNS record entries.
The DNS record entries would have allowed you to configure the locations of your mail servers, web server etc.

It seems like wherever you bought your .com domain from does not let you do this. What you can do is specify the nameservers which contains the above records for your domain.

You will find some free ones here (search for nameserver hosting in google)
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/21/free-dns-name-server-hosting-services/